# Erro no Visualg na variável REAL

Tags: visualg

No algoritmo abaixo, o visualg informa: Esperava expressão do tipo REAL. Isso sempre acontece quando digito 1.88 ou qualquer número com decimais na variável (a). Porém a variável não está como inteiro como vcs podem ver. Como posso solucionar isso? Obrigado!

```
algoritmo "CALCULOIMC"
var
      M, A, IMC: Real
inicio

      Escreva("Massa (KG): ")
      Leia(M)
      Escreva ("Altura (m): ")
      Leia(A)
      IMC <- M / (A ^ 2)
      Escreval ("IMC: ", IMC)


fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Fiz um teste com seu exemplo e não gerou exceção, talvez seja a versão do visualg, veja se existe atualização.

Comment: Fábio, eu estava com o mesmo problema. Eu fechei e abri o Visualg e voltou a funcionar a lógica. Deve ser algum BUG. Abs

Answer (score 0):

Esse código não tem erros de sintaxe. O código está funcionando normalmente.

Possíveis causas do problema:

- algum caractere inválido. Experimente copiar o texto daqui da postagem ou simplesmente abra um arquivo novo e redigite;
- seu programa VisualG com bug. Experimente reinstalar o VisualG ou baixe a versão 3.0.6.5, a mais estável. (Existe a 3.0.7.0, mas não recomendo.)

Adendo: tanto faz usar "." ou "," no VisualG.

Segue teste na versão 2.5
[image: Teste de execução na versão 2.5 do VisualG]

Segue teste na versão 3.0.6.5
[image: Teste de execução na versão 3.0.6.5 do VisualG]